# Why does \lefthyphenmin sometimes escape its containing group?

Tags: xetex, hyphenation, grouping

In the following example, `subsequently` is hyphenated in the first two cases as well as in the fourth one, but not in the third.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \texttt{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing} elit subsequently.
\item \texttt{\lefthyphenmin=62 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing} elit subsequently.
\item {\ttfamily\lefthyphenmin=62 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing} elit subsequently.
\item {\ttfamily Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing} elit subsequently.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

What makes the third line different? Using `\showthe\lefthyphenmin` in the third line shows that it has properly reverted to 2 after the `\ttfamily` group, so it must be something else; but what?

Comment: this is a good question:-)

Answer (score 3):

The difference is whether the setting is in horizontal or vertical mode, ie before or in the paragraph, compare the 3rd and 4th versions below. I adjusted the example slightly so pdftex or xetex can be used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\advance\textwidth-15pt
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \texttt{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing} elit subsequently.
\item \texttt{\lefthyphenmin=62 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing} elit subsequently.
\item {\ttfamily\lefthyphenmin=62 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing} elit subsequently.
\item \leavevmode{\ttfamily\lefthyphenmin=62 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing} elit subsequently.
\item {\ttfamily Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing} elit subsequently.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fascinating, thanks! But what causes the third line to be in vertical mode, while the fifth one is not?

Comment: @Clément it's where the nodes setting lefthyphenmin end up, the fith doesn't set it at all, `\texttt` starts with an implicit `\leavevmode` and the extra one i added has explicit `\leavevmode` I may see if I can track down some documentation for this behaviour later, was too late last night:-)

Comment: Neat, thanks! Documentation would be great; I couldn't find much before asking here.

Comment: @Clément see http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31564688#31564688 (ongoing..)